# Meteor - Trouble using return value from Meteor.call

Tags: javascript, meteor

I’m probably showing my javascript ignorance here, but why doesn’t this work? And how can I do rewrite this piece of code to make it work?

```
// On the client
Template.tabs.title = function () {
  var msg;
  Meteor.call('getMessage', this.msg_id, function (error, result) {
    console.log(result); // Prints out a perfectly fine message object
    msg = result;
  });
  if (msg)
    return msg.title;
  else
    return "(empty)"; // This is always the value that's shown on the page
};
```

My understanding of the problem is that the "if" statement gets executed before the callback can set the msg variable. Is that right? Or is it a scoping problem? Can I even do it like this, calling "call" from the template?

The reason I’m using methods here it that the Messages collection can potentially be huge, and I can’t subscribe to it as a whole on the client. I have subscriptions for parts of it, but I also need to look up arbitrary messages, no matter what my subscriptions have available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the callback not being set yet when you examine `msg`. I guess the best thing to do is just set a `Session` var when the callback returns and rely on Meteor's reactivity to redraw your message when that happens. Something like:

```
Template.tabs.title = function () {
  var title = Session.get('currentTitle');

  if (title) {
    return 'title';
  else {
    Meteor.call('getMessage', this.msg_id, function (error, msg) {
      Session.set('currentTitle', msg ? msg.title : "(empty)");
    });
  }
};
```

On the other hand I'd probably say using a single-message subscription to grab the 'current message' would make more sense and be more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did manage to hack this together by using dynamically named sessions, but it didn’t feel quite right. Now that I’ve grokked multiple subscriptions for the same collection, I agree that the proper way to solve this is with a single-message subscription. But I’m still curious about how one would use the result of a methods call in a template, and it’s not clear to me whether alcidesqueiroz’s callback solution is actually doable. Consequently, I’m still not sure which answer is the best...

Comment: It's not. Template helpers are synchronous.

Comment: In that case I suppose this is the correct answer. Thanks again, Tom!

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter passed for the "call" method is an asyncronous callback, when you try to return your "msg" variable, it's not defined yet.

Use another callback, like this:

```
Template.tabs.retrieveTitle(callback){
  Meteor.call('getMessage', this.msg_id, function (error, result) {
   callback( (result) ? result.title : "(empty)" );
  });
}
```

And you could use the above method this way:

```
Template.tabs.retrieveTitle(function(){
//do what you want to
});
```

Comment: Right, that's what I suspected. But how, exactly, do I use a callback to solve my problem? I can't just put the return statements in the callback, because the template won't see the result from that. I need to somehow return the return value of the "call" call from the template helper.

Comment: Thanks for the code. My understanding of the docs is that call without a callback on the client will always return undefined (and my experiments seem to confirm it). So I still don’t quite see how to achieve my goal.

Comment: You're right, I read the reference too quicly to see this =D. Let me think if there's another way.

Comment: Well, Meteor really doesn't give you many alternatives. And to force a synchronous behavior would not really be the best way to work with JS running in a browser. I think that, unfortunately, you'll have to deal with callbacks to do this job.

Comment: I don't mind using callbacks, I just don't understand how to do it in a template context. In your example, how would I call the helper with the callback from the handlebar template? As far as I know you can't send in a function as an argument from the template. If this was just regular JavaScript I could probably figure this out, but I just don't understand how {{title}} in the template can insert the return value from the callback.